# Why does #available(iOS 11, *) resolve to true on iOS 12?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, ios12

My understanding of the `#available` syntax was that it was specifying the major / minor versions of iOS.  However, I am noticing that code protected by this `if` clause will be executed on **iOS 12**.

Is it expected that `#available` resolves to a `>=` check?

It appears to do this whether it has been compiled by the current version of Xcode (**targeting iOS 11**) as well as the beta version targeting **iOS**

Comment: Is it expected that #available resolves to a >= check? - Yes it will check the from available to current 

https://www.raywenderlich.com/139077/availability-attributes-swift

Comment: that is how it supposed to work.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification and the link.  I tried to find the Apple documentation for it and couldn't...

Comment: Why do you downvote a valid question?  Just post the answer and or a link showing the answer in some kind of official documentation.  Honestly, people won't post questions if we treat them like fools for doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is expected. `#available` is meant to be used to enclose functions that have been added in specific iOS version, that are available since that version forward.